# Change host and port that mongod listens to dynamicly at run time

Tags: mongodb

If one starts mongod and binds it to localhost and a custom port by running:

```
mongod --bind_ip localhost --port 1234
```

can one change the bound ip/port at runtime through something like mongo shell without having to restart mongod ?

Comment: No, you can't. Why would you want to? It would disconnect all clients -- firewalls might not be open, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MongoDB does not support this feature.